# Android App Taking 11 % of battery life is that good nature

Tags: android, batterylevel

Here I created an application that based on GPS, service, Broadcast receivers, What am doing is calling location updates in every 5 mins later sending those to webserver. So, now my app is taking 11 % batter life. Is that a good nature.

Comment: 11% in how many time ? in one hour ? in one day ?

Comment: How can one describe the amount of battery life an app should use? It really depends on what the app does, and within what time limit. Obviously, from a user (and developer) point of view, it is critical to use as little as possible battery life as possible. You need to consider if the battery life you are using is outweighed by what your app does.

Comment: do you use alarmmanager?

Comment: yes i use alarmManager

Answer (score 0):

I think 11% is quite high.

You could think about changing a bit the way you are calling for location updates. Maybe do something more like Geofencing logic. 
This might help: https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325337477